# How do I download an Edited Image that is In a Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm currently working on a Image editor and I have it inside of a Canvas, and It's changing the picture that is inside of the Canvas, but when you go to right click and save  the image as, it comes out as the original image still not the edited one, I also had this problem even when It wasn't inside of the Canvas.

Here's What it looks Like Edited in the Canvas: 
[Edited Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrBHm.png)

And What it Looks Like After You save it: [Saved Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDRyj.jpg)

Here's My Filters Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".range").change(add_filter).mousemove(add_filter);
});

function add_filter()
{
var grayscale_val=$("#grayscale").val();
var blur_val=$("#blur").val();
var exposure_val=$("#exposure").val();
var sepia_val=$("#sepia").val();
var opacity_val=$("#opacity").val();

$("#canvas").css("-webkit-filter","grayscale("+grayscale_val+"%) blur("+blur_val+"px) brightness("+exposure_val+"%) sepia("+sepia_val+"%) opacity("+opacity_val+"%)");
}
</script>
```

Here's my HTML :

```
<div id="buttons">
<li>GrayScale<br><input id="grayscale" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"></li>

<li>Blur<br><input id="blur" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0"></li>

<li>Exposure<br><input id="exposure" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100"></li>

<li>Sepia<br><input id="sepia" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"></li>

<li>Opacity<br><input id="opacity" class="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100"></li>


<div id="image_div">
<canvas id="canvas"  id="edit_image" height="600" width="600" ></canvas>
<input type='file' name='img' id='uploadimage' />

</div>
```

Code That Will upload the selected Image into the Canvas:

```
function draw(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image(),
        f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
        url = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
        src = url.createObjectURL(f);

    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        url.revokeObjectURL(src);
    }
}

document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

</script>
```

Thank You In Advance!

Comment: You're going to have to save as PNG if you expect to support alpha channel.

Comment: so then they would only be able to upload png images to edit? or have it where it will change the format of the image after its done being edited by the user, then download it?

Comment: Also, you're not even applying the changes to the canvas... your CSS is simply changing how the canvas is displayed.  Consider using SVG if you want to manipulate images this way.

Comment: Ah ok So I need to ctx the Filters. :) Thanks You!